# Is it possible to tell the difference between a "conversion tracking pixel" and a "facebook pixel" based on pixel id?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, analytics

As of July 15th users can no longer create "conversion tracking pixels" according to https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1686199411616919. If I have a database of facebook pixels, is it possible to tell if it is a new pixel or an old pixel based on the pixel id? I need to know which pixel bootstrapping code to use in the html depending on if it is an old or new pixel.

I have tried using github's code search to see if there is a pattern between the ids that people are using for the new bootstrapping code vs. the old code but so far have not seen a pattern.

Comment: How much of facebooks documentation have you read? for instance - [How do I transition ...](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1058078787600162?helpref=faq_content)

Comment: I have combed through it for quite some time before posting this question, however I found nothing which could help me determine if a given pixel id is an "old" or "new" one. I could have very well missed something though.

Comment: I haven't looked at it at all, I just thought an article which was entitled **how do I transition from conversion tracking pixel to facebook pixel** would explain everything you need to know about the **transition** from one to the other. Sorry for wasting your time

Comment: You are not wasting time, I am sincerly hoping there is documentation that I missed. That particular article outlines how a site owner can transition their pixel from the old to the new values, replacing the old bootstrapping code along the way. My issue is that I am creating a tool for a bunch of customers, each with their own pixel ids, which will place the pixel js code on their custom page, but I don't know if I should use the old or new bootstrapping code in this purgatory where both types are supported.